# problems of initialization with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, avplayer

Please I need help, My problem is that i when migrate Swift3 for Swift4, in some methods appears problems of syntax.
the msg of erro is: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'

```
func setupPreviewLayer() {

    let layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraMan.session)
    layer.backgroundColor = configuration.mainColor.cgColor
    layer.autoreverses = true
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    layer.frame = view.layer.frame
    view.clipsToBounds = true

    previewLayer = layer
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me. Rewrite your line (6) as follow:

```
layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity(rawValue: convertFromAVLayerVideoGravity(AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill))
```